# External Entry Point Issue - Any Suggestion/Solution

Tags: unit-test, apex, standardsetcontroller

Here is my Class

```
public with sharing class MassDeleteLeadController {

public MassDeleteLeadController (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
       currentStep = '1';
       controller.setPageSize(1000);
       step1Render =true;

       cntr = (ApexPages.StandardSetController)controller;
       fromPage = cntr.cancel();
       if (this.objs == null) {
            this.objs = (List<SObject>)cntr.getSelected();
       }
       if (getRecordSize()<1) {
            String msg = 'No record was selected on the list view.  Please click Previous button and select records for mass update.'; 
            currentMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, msg);
       } else {
            sType= discoverSObjectType(objs.get(0)).getName(); 
            String msg = 'Number of records selected for update: ' + getRecordSize(); 
            currentMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, msg);
       }
       ApexPages.addMessage(currentMsg);


   }

    public PageReference step1() {
        if(getRecordSize()<1) return fromPage;      
        currentStep='1';          
        return ApexPages.currentPage();
    }
}
```

This is Test Class I am trying

```
    @isTest
    public with sharing class MassDeleteLeadControllerTest{

        public static testMethod void validateMassDeleteLeadController(){
            Boolean flag=True;

            Lead objLead = new Lead();
            objLead.LastName='Test Last';
            objLead.Company='Test company';
            objLead.Status='Test Status';
            insert objLead;


            List<sObject> lstLead = new List<sObject>();
            lstLead.add((sObject)objLead);

            ApexPages.StandardSetController setController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(lstLead);
            setController.setSelected(lstLead);

            MassDeleteLeadController controller = new MassDeleteLeadController(setController);
            controller.step1();

}
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is?

Comment: What is the exact error message you're receiving? Is it when you run the test class or at some other time? Its unclear your your problem is. Also, is there a specific VisualForce page you're running this from when you have the problem? If so, posting that code would likely be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Simply changing following line in TestClass

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController setController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(lstLead);
```

except of this, I did

```
ApexPages.StandardSetController setController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([select id,LastName from Lead]);
```

and `(SeeAllData=True)` at very first Line of the Test Class. Removed "External Entry Point" stack trace error and passed my Test Class.

Answer (score 0):

Off hand, I see no getters or setters defined for your controller. Both your `MassDeleteLeadController` and `PageReference step1` methods refer to `getRecordSize()`, but the latter isn't defined. You also have a reference to `setPageSize(1000)` which also isn't defined with a setter method. You need to pass these to and from the controller.

I recommend you review the following resources: [Visualforce Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/workbook_vf_intro.htm) and the [Visualforce Developer’s Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm).